# C char qsort in array of pointers to strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, qsort

I have an array of pointers to string:

```
char *TAB[3] = { "dafafa", "alfkasf", "bafgr" };
```

I would like to sort characters in in each of those strings.

My compare function:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
   return *(char *)a - *(char *)b; 
}
```

and while trying qsort on one of these:

```
qsort(TAB[0], 6, sizeof(char), cmp);
```

The program doesn't work.
After many efforts I found that the reason of the problem is in delivering `TAB[0]` to `qsort()`.

Can anyone explain why it doesn't work and how to fix that?

Comment: Literal strings in C are *read only*. Attempting to modify them leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: "I would like to sort characters in in each of those strings." --> and where would you like to put that sorted string given that writing to the source string, a _string literal_, is _undefined behavior_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sort characters inside each string, the first thing you must ensure is that your strings can be written to. As it currently stands, your strings are read-only, so you cannot sort their characters without copying their content into memory that allows writing.

Next thing is that you need a loop. Since you are sorting each string individually, you need to loop through the array, and call `qsort` on each item. The initial item is `TAB[i]`, and the length is `strlen(TAB[i])`. Your `cmp` function will work.

Comment: How do you know that those strings are read-only? Could you show me code example which can fix that?

I've checked that after declaring `char tab[]="dafafa"` instead of `char* tab="dafafa"` it worked. Whats the difference there?

Comment: @PiotrWitkoś All string literals are read-only, in the sense that you are not allowed to change their content. `char tab[]="dafafa"` is different, because you initialize an array of characters with a string literal. This array becomes writable. `TAB[3]` in your original code is an array of pointers, so it is very much like `char* tab="dafafa"` repeated three times. You can check [here](https://ideone.com/1eqKyG) to see how to properly copy strings.

Comment: I have a question in my exam to sort characters in every string in an array of strings `TAB[100]`. How would you declare it to avoid copying the content?

Comment: @PiotrWitkoś `char TAB[3][100]={"dafafa","alfkasf","bafgr"};` will do the trick ([demo](https://ideone.com/BHOwWI)).